# HTTP Error WordPress, no issue on proxy

Tags: php, wordpress, proxy

I am trying to upload file which is of 2.54MB, my server maximum upload limit is 30MB when i tried to upload it, it gives me error "HTTP Error", i am just searching for that error from very long time. Increased WP Memeor y limit, execution time nothing works. But when i changed my proxy and tried to upload via USA proxy it works. I have deactivated all the plugins swithced to basic theme, cleared .httacces but nothing works for me :( 
Please let me know how can i resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: At what point did it work? You changed proxy and it worked, right? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, when i changed the proxy it works.

Comment: Do you think it might be cache issues? Clear browser cache and test again. Also change browser to see if it works.

Comment: Yes, tried but no success.

Comment: can you give us a link?

Comment: Here is the link : http://imtrade.com.au/

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Web Host's **control panel**

Go to your **File Manager**

Change directory to your WordPress' **Admin folder**

Create a `php.ini` file

Click **Edit** to edit the contents of the newly created file.

Inside of it paste

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Save file.

Refresh the WordPress page you are editing and try again.